# How to use union all when using order by clause SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union, sql-server-2014

Here is my query however it is getting error

The error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.

The query

```
(SELECT TOP 20 cl_RooSiteId,
               cl_CrawlOrgUrl
 FROM   tblCrawlUrls
 WHERE  Sysutcdatetime() > Dateadd(MINUTE, 50000, cl_LastCrawlDate)
        AND cl_DuplicateUrl_ByCanonical = 0
        AND cl_RooSiteId = 1
 ORDER  BY cl_LastCrawlDate ASC)
UNION ALL
(SELECT TOP 200 cl_RooSiteId,
                cl_CrawlOrgUrl
 FROM   tblCrawlUrls
 WHERE  Sysutcdatetime() > Dateadd(MINUTE, 50000, cl_LastCrawlDate)
        AND cl_DuplicateUrl_ByCanonical = 0
        AND cl_RooSiteId = 2
 ORDER  BY cl_LastCrawlDate ASC)
UNION ALL
(SELECT TOP 50 cl_RooSiteId,
               cl_CrawlOrgUrl
 FROM   tblCrawlUrls
 WHERE  Sysutcdatetime() > Dateadd(MINUTE, 50000, cl_LastCrawlDate)
        AND cl_DuplicateUrl_ByCanonical = 0
        AND cl_RooSiteId = 3
 ORDER  BY cl_LastCrawlDate ASC)
```

So how should write it in a way that it should work?

Comment: You cannot put an order by between UNION (ALL) create a top level SELECT then put the order by there.

Comment: @agentpx so how can i achieve what i want to achieve ? I also tried encapsulating them in a upper level select but it also failed

Comment: ty i see MSSQL is not capable what i am asking so it seems best to return each query as a table then process at my code behind. each query need to be sorted individually not the returned results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the query results into `temp table` and use `Union all`

```
SELECT TOP 20 cl_RooSiteId,
              cl_CrawlOrgUrl,cl_LastCrawlDate
INTO   #Temp1
FROM   tblCrawlUrls
WHERE  Sysutcdatetime() > Dateadd(MINUTE, 50000, cl_LastCrawlDate)
       AND cl_DuplicateUrl_ByCanonical = 0
       AND cl_RooSiteId = 1
ORDER  BY cl_LastCrawlDate ASC

SELECT TOP 200 cl_RooSiteId,
               cl_CrawlOrgUrl,cl_LastCrawlDate
INTO   #temp2
FROM   tblCrawlUrls
WHERE  Sysutcdatetime() > Dateadd(MINUTE, 50000, cl_LastCrawlDate)
       AND cl_DuplicateUrl_ByCanonical = 0
       AND cl_RooSiteId = 2
ORDER  BY cl_LastCrawlDate ASC

SELECT TOP 50 cl_RooSiteId,
              cl_CrawlOrgUrl,cl_LastCrawlDate
INTO   #temp3
FROM   tblCrawlUrls
WHERE  Sysutcdatetime() > Dateadd(MINUTE, 50000, cl_LastCrawlDate)
       AND cl_DuplicateUrl_ByCanonical = 0
       AND cl_RooSiteId = 3
ORDER  BY cl_LastCrawlDate ASC

SELECT cl_RooSiteId,cl_CrawlOrgUrl FROM   #Temp1
UNION ALL
SELECT cl_RooSiteId,cl_CrawlOrgUrl FROM   #Temp2
UNION ALL
SELECT cl_RooSiteId,cl_CrawlOrgUrl FROM   #Temp3 
Order by cl_LastCrawlDate
```

Or use `Stacked CTE`

```
;WITH cte1
     AS (SELECT TOP 20 cl_RooSiteId,
                       cl_CrawlOrgUrl,cl_LastCrawlDate
         FROM   tblCrawlUrls
         WHERE  Sysutcdatetime() > Dateadd(MINUTE, 50000, cl_LastCrawlDate)
                AND cl_DuplicateUrl_ByCanonical = 0
                AND cl_RooSiteId = 1
         ORDER  BY cl_LastCrawlDate ASC),
     cte2
     AS (SELECT TOP 200 cl_RooSiteId,
                        cl_CrawlOrgUrl,cl_LastCrawlDate
         FROM   tblCrawlUrls
         WHERE  Sysutcdatetime() > Dateadd(MINUTE, 50000, cl_LastCrawlDate)
                AND cl_DuplicateUrl_ByCanonical = 0
                AND cl_RooSiteId = 2
         ORDER  BY cl_LastCrawlDate ASC),
     cte3
     AS (SELECT TOP 50 cl_RooSiteId,
                       cl_CrawlOrgUrl,cl_LastCrawlDate
         FROM   tblCrawlUrls
         WHERE  Sysutcdatetime() > Dateadd(MINUTE, 50000, cl_LastCrawlDate)
                AND cl_DuplicateUrl_ByCanonical = 0
                AND cl_RooSiteId = 3
         ORDER  BY cl_LastCrawlDate ASC)
SELECT cl_RooSiteId,cl_CrawlOrgUrl FROM   cte1
UNION ALL
SELECT cl_RooSiteId,cl_CrawlOrgUrl FROM   cte2
UNION ALL
SELECT cl_RooSiteId,cl_CrawlOrgUrl FROM   cte3 
ORDER  BY cl_LastCrawlDate ASC
```

Comment: ty for answer already tried that it is also not working error : Msg 104, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG - Updated try now.

Comment: ty i see MSSQL is not capable what i am asking so it seems best to return each query as a table then process at my code behind. each query need to be sorted individually not the returned results.

Comment: ok this seems like working good however i need to remove temp tables at each query also using temp tables seems like bringing a lot of extra overhead to the sql server

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG - check now you can also use `stacked CTE`

Comment: @NoDisplayName . . . Presumably, the OP wants the output ordered in a particularly way.  With no `order by` in the outer query, the ordering is not guaranteed.

Comment: @GordonLinoff output order is not important. only individual select queries order is important to recrawl very first links

Comment: stacked cte seems like great ty for answer

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Updated to order the result

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you want these in the order you have written them:

```
SELECT cl_RooSiteId, cl_CrawlOrgUrl
FROM ((SELECT TOP 20 cl_RooSiteId, cl_CrawlOrgUrl, cl_LastCrawlDate, 0 as priority
       FROM   tblCrawlUrls
       WHERE  Sysutcdatetime() > Dateadd(MINUTE, 50000, cl_LastCrawlDate) AND
              cl_DuplicateUrl_ByCanonical = 0 AND
              cl_RooSiteId = 1
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT TOP 200 cl_RooSiteId, cl_CrawlOrgUrl, cl_LastCrawlDate, 1 as priority
       FROM   tblCrawlUrls
       WHERE  Sysutcdatetime() > Dateadd(MINUTE, 50000, cl_LastCrawlDate) AND
              cl_DuplicateUrl_ByCanonical = 0 AND
              cl_RooSiteId = 2
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT TOP 50 cl_RooSiteId, cl_CrawlOrgUrl, cl_LastCrawlDate, 2
       FROM   tblCrawlUrls
       WHERE  Sysutcdatetime() > Dateadd(MINUTE, 50000, cl_LastCrawlDate) AND
              cl_DuplicateUrl_ByCanonical = 0 AND
              cl_RooSiteId = 3
      )
    ) c
ORDER BY priority, cl_LastCrawlDate ASC
```

Note the inclusion of `priority` and `cl_LastCrawlDate` in the subqueries.  I realize that `priority` is redundant because you can use `ORDER BY cl_RooSiteId, cl_LastCrawlDate`.

EDIT:

You can also do this without `union all`:

```
SELECT cl_RooSiteId, cl_CrawlOrgUrl
FROM (SELECT c.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cl_RooSiteId ORDER BY cl_LastCrawlDate) as seqnum
      FROM tblCrawlUrls c
      WHERE  Sysutcdatetime() > Dateadd(MINUTE, 50000, cl_LastCrawlDate) AND
             cl_DuplicateUrl_ByCanonical = 0
     ) c
WHERE (cl_RooSiteId = 1 and seqnum <= 20) OR
      (cl_RooSiteId = 2 and seqnum <= 200) OR
      (cl_RooSiteId = 3 and seqnum <= 50)
ORDER BY cl_RooSiteId, cl_LastCrawlDate;
```

Comment: the order of combined results are not important. only individual selections order is important to retrieve very first not crawled urls. your second query is not working also giving error  Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Comment: just give the derived table a name   )  derivedTable

Comment: This deserved the check +1

Answer (score 1):

A common table expression should do the trick [SEE THIS LINK](https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%2528v%3Dsql.105%2529.aspx&ei=XcOeVOe8GIOQuQTvjIHYCQ&usg=AFQjCNFZYj6txuznGZIBIQYh_MEp0X0Vqg&sig2=TrUNjpXp7vpRDK-czWcu_g&bvm=bv.82001339,d.c2E)

A common table expression (CTE) can be thought of as a temporary result set that is defined within the execution scope of a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW statement. A CTE is similar to a derived table in that it is not stored as an object and lasts only for the duration of the query. Unlike a derived table, a CTE can be self-referencing and can be referenced multiple times in the same query.

Here's a snippets

```
WITH TopLevel( colum1, column2, ...) AS 
(
   SELECT column1, column2, ...
   FROM table1  --without ORDER BY

   UNION ALL

   SELECT column1, column2, ...
   FROM table2 --without ORDER BY
   .
   .
   .

)
SELECT * FROM 
FROM TopLevel
ORDER BY column1, column2... --ORDER BY HERE...
```

Comment: ty i see MSSQL is not capable what i am asking so it seems best to return each query as a table then process at my code behind. each query need to be sorted individually not the returned results.